# TeamCity Running Too Many Builds

Tags: github, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have created a build configuration in TeamCity (v8.0.1) to automatically build my Github pull requests by setting my VCS branch specification to +:refs/pull/(*/merge) (I followed [this](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity/) blog post).

TeamCity is picking up new pull requests and changes to existing pull requests just fine, however it is kicking off multiple builds per change when I would expect it to only perform a single build.

For example, I pushed up two commits to an existing pull request which resulted in 8 builds being executed by TeamCity. When I look at the changes for each of the builds the change graph is identical except for the commit hash of the pull request's build (at least I think that is what it is), e.g.

[image]
[image]

I have confirmed that Per-checkin Triggering is disabled in the Build Trigger configuration. I have also confirmed that we are not using any of Github's TeamCity hooks.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what could cause this, but have you tried to turn on "Quiet Period"
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers